# TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key for Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm working out this tutorial from Medium ([here](https://towardsdatascience.com/getting-rich-quick-with-machine-learning-and-stock-market-predictions-696802da94fe)) and I've copied the code almost verbatim, but when I run the code, I am getting the following error in the line with the double asterisks:

"TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 0)' is an invalid key"

Can someone help me out with working out the code?

```
data_normaliser = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
data_normalised = data_normaliser.fit_transform(data)

ohlcv_histories_normalised = np.array([data_normalised[i:i + history_points].copy() for i in range(len(data_normalised) - history_points)])
next_day_open_values_normalised = np.array([data_normalised[:, 0][i + history_points].copy() for i in range(len(data_normalised) - history_points)])
next_day_open_values_normalised = np.expand_dims(next_day_open_values_normalised, -1)

**next_day_open_values = np.array([data[:, 0][i + history_points].copy() for i in range(len(data) - history_points)])**
next_day_open_values = np.expand_dims(next_day_open_values, -1)

y_normaliser = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
y_normaliser.fit(np.expand_dims(next_day_open_values))

assert ohlcv_histories_normalised.shape[0] == next_day_open_values_normalised.shape[0]
return ohlcv_histories_normalised, next_day_open_values_normalised, next_day_open_values, y_normaliser
```